# Django stuck after doing code change (hot reload not working)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pipenv, hot-reload

I upgraded my Django version from `3.2.15` to `4.2.1` and also my Python version from `3.7.13` to `3.11.0` and the hot reload of my Django project stopped working.

The server starts as expected with the `pipenv run python src/manage.py runserver {host}:{port}` command, but when I do a code change and save the file the server gets stuck saying:

`[INFO] [django]: /my-route/my-file.py changed, reloading`

And I have to kill the process on the console and start it again to make it work.

When I had my old dependencies, after saving a file the server just reloaded and it showed the changes.

I tried to set the verbosity to 3, but I can't get any information explaining the error and I don't know how to debug it. It looks like it uses `StatReloader` to detect this file changes:

`[INFO] [django]: Watching for file changes with StatReloader` gets printed before starting the server.

I would really appreciate it if you can give me some help or direction to follow about this topic.

Thanks in advance!